# Use of LIKE clause in sql prepared statement, spring, SimpleJDBCTemplate

Tags: sql, spring, jdbc, prepared-statement, sql-like

I have the following sql prepared statement:

```
SELECT * FROM video WHERE video_name LIKE ?
```

Im using spring and jdbc.
i have a method, where term is a searchterm, sjt is a SimpleJdbcTemplate, VideoMapper is a RowMapper and searchForTermQuery is the string from above

```
...
return sjt.query(searchForTermQuery, new VideoMapper(), term);
```

My table has 2 videos that match the term.
However when I run the query none is found. I get an empty List.

I tried playing with % around the question mark, but it only gave badGrammarExceptions.

Comment: try appending the % to the search string on each end... `term = '%' + term + '%';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the `%` around the value itself, not around the placeholder (the question mark).

So:

```
return sjt.query(searchForTermQuery, new VideoMapper(), "%" + term + "%");
```